# Java project dependencies

Tags: java

Let us assume I have a dynamic web project named A. This project A has a dependency on another Project named B that uses a Dom4J jar. If B adds this jar as a dependency and I add project B in project A's buildpath and in project B there is a method that throws a Dom4J Exception, how can I avoid adding Dom4J as a dependency in project A, so that I don't have the Dom4J in both projects as a dependency?

Comment: This depending on your build system. Maven and Gradle do this by default and you have to explicitly prevent this if you don't want it.  Most IDEs also export transient dependencies.  While build tool are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code directly calls a method that declares to throw Dom4jException you will need to have Dom4j on your build classpath. That's just part of the method signature, and the compiler must be able to resolve it.

If that is an issue (i.e. you want to hide the existance of Dom4j as an "implementation detail" of Project B), then you need to make sure that none of Project B's public-facing API exposes any Dom4j classes. You could for example change the `throws` clause to widen to an appropriate public exception or wrap the exception.

Note that this problem only occurs if Project A access a class in Project B that refers to Dom4J directly. It's not an issue for internal classes that you don't directly compile against. Of course, you still need Dom4J at runtime.

Lastly, in Maven, by default you get all transitive compile-time dependencies in your compile-time classpath as well. So Dom4J will be there already, you should not be getting build errors. But it is good practice to explicily include it directly if you are going to make use of Dom4J (for example by catching the exception).

Comment: Thanks, I thought there could be a workaround on this. So adding that jar on both classpaths is the pnly solution, right? I will mark your answer as accepted as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

You can't because project A needs to be aware of the dom4j exception. The only way would be to modify project B to not throw the dom4j exception. Typically this is done by catching the exception in B and throw a more common exception or handle the exception there.